# Redux reducer state change doesn't trigger life cycle methods

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get the new state after the reducer update it in a React Life Cycle methods like componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate and need to re-render component accordingly. But I see the changed log in console but it neither triggers the lifeCycleMethods nor it triggers the component to rerender

Initially, in my reducer I used Object.assign like this:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
            emailAddr: action.data
        });
```

But realized after reading some StackOverflow answers that this won't work. So, I also tried below things suggested by few answers.

```
state = {
                ...state,
                emailAddr: action.data,
            };

            console.log("newState: ", state);


            return state;
```

and

```
  return {
            ...state,
            emailAddr: action.data,
        };
```

None of this triggers any lifeCycleMethods.

emailReducer.js

```
export default function emailInfo(state = {
    emailAddr: '',
}, action){

    switch(action.type){

        case 'SENT_EMAIL_DATA':
            debugger;
            console.log("state when email address sent: ", state);
            console.log("action.data when email address sent: ", action.data);
            // return Object.assign({}, state, {
            //     emailAddr: action.data
            // });

            state = {
                ...state,
                emailAddr: action.data,
            };

            console.log("newState: ", state);


            return state;
            // return {
            //     ...state,
            //     emailAddr: action.data,
            // };


        default: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

action.js

```
import { API_URL } from '../global';
import axios from 'axios';

export const sentEmailData = data => {
    return {
        type: 'SENT_EMAIL_DATA',
        data
    };
};


export function submitEmail( data) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.post(API_URL, {
            emailAddr: data
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.errors === null ) {
                    console.log("response 2222: ", response);
                    dispatch(sentEmailData(response));
                } else {
                    throw new Error(response.data.errors[0].statusMessage);
                }

            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log("err 2222: ", err);
            });
    }
}
```

I understand that reducers has to return new object. If we mutate the object, component doesn't get re-render. But not sure what else I am missing

Comment: Can you share the component you're expecting to re-render and how you're using `connect` to hook it up to the store?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the speedy response. I just found a solution after reading thread on https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/585. But, your guess was right problem was in my connect

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so any other user having the same issue, I had everything correct except in my component I didn't use mapStateToProps. So, my component couldn't listen to the changes from store.

I realized it after reading thread on https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/585. Here after reading a comment by @andrewchumich, i changed component and everything starts working.

[image]